# Obter Token de acesso no Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic, http

Através do prompt de comando eu obtenho um acess token.

`curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \ -H "Accept: application/json" \ -H "Accept-Language: pt_BR" \ -u "my-client_id:my-client_secret" \ -d "grant_type=client_credentials"`

No projeto eu uso esse token e recebo um json.

Service.ts

```
getPayment() {
let token = 'A21AAGsiyUhk3ntiu7MMtkvc_aTKaXyWHdfKRrMV0qqNyPQ1ZzxXrT2oxGGdz8wLVcgZzmwgQ8r1mdMLprw0vsB374AI8D2AA';
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", [`Bearer ${token}`]).set("Content-Type", "application/json")
}
return this.http.get("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1826783671569693VLQ2IYVQ", httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Component.ts

```
  this.authService.getPayment().subscribe((response) => {
   console.log('abcde', JSON.stringify(response))
 });
```

Porém, eu preciso gerar esse Token automaticamente, mas não sei como enviar meu Client_ID e Secret por parâmetro.  Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Voce tem que fazer uma requisição get para essa URL passando esses parametros.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, talvez dê para entender um pouco melhor.  Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguém precise algum dia, aqui está a solução que consegui:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
    uri: "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en_US",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    auth: {
        'user': 'SEU CLIENT ID',
        'pass': 'SEU CLIENT SECRET',
        // 'sendImmediately': false
    },
    form: {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials"
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

se `require` não for aceito:

> `npm i @types/node` 
>   e adicione:
>
> ```
> "types": [
>     "node"
> ],
> "typeRoots": [
>     "node_modules/@types"
> ]
> ```
>
> no arquivo `tsconfig.json`
>   e também: `declare var require: any;` em seu componente

Answer (score -2):

```
pegarToken(){
 const auth = btoa(`${this.clientId}:${this.clientSecret}`);//substitui pelo seu id e secret
 return `Bearer ${auth}`;
}


getPayment() {
let token = this.pegarToken();
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", token).set("Content-Type", "application/json")
}
return this.http.get("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1826783671569693VLQ2IYVQ", httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder, mas onde eu chamo  "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token"  ?   Não entendi muito bem, pode me dar uma explicação?  Thx

Comment: na hora que vc der o subscribe no seu componente ele vai fazer essa requisição http. Toda vez que vc der subscribe no observable do retorno da funçao ele vai fazer a requisição.